# EF Core Expresssion execution with different finalizator types

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I use EF Core 3.1.2.

I try to execute an Expression, generated by same query like this:

```
var dataQuery = testDb.Users
    .Include(e => e.EmployeeInfo)
    .Include(f => f.Notifications)
    .Where(s => tstList.Contains(s.Id))
    .Select(e => e.FullName);
var expression = dataQuery.Expression;
```

Here `testDb` is an object of an inherited class from EF Core `DbContext with different tables. The structure of`DbSet` isn't significant in the current question.

So, I tried to get provider for `testDb` by this code:

```
var providerAsync = testDb.GetService<IAsyncQueryProvider>();
```

It gives me a provider, but the code `var result = providerAsync.Execute(expression);` execution fails with an error:

> Expression of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1[System.String]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String]'

So, I have 2 questions here:

1) How to execute Expressions and how to execute expressions async if I don't know the `TResult` type for ExecuteAsync method from `IAsyncQueryProvider`?
2) How to implement different `finalizators` like `ToListAsync()`, `ToArrayAsync()`, and of course, `finalizators` with Lambda Body like `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` and etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Try declaring your `providerAsync` variable as type `IAsyncQueryProvider`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the method `ExecuteAsync`?

Comment: Why do you need all that? One normally don't work directly with `IQueryable<T>` provider / expression. Enumerating `IQueryable<T>` does execute it. And all "finalizators" you are asking are provided by EF Core queryable extensions.

Comment: @IvanStoev: There might be a reason.  The OP hasn't provided any details about how their application works, so.

Comment: So, let me explain the reason. I try to realize my own serializer for an Expression. After deserialization I get only an object of  Expression class which represents my request to the ef core provider. I don't know the Expression result type on compilation time, just only on runtime, unfortunatelly. And I really can't use ExecuteAsync meyhod here for this reason.

Comment: @ Ivan Stoev, sure, I could realize direct call to thr database, but I use microservice architecture, so, It's so hard to realize caching and complex transactions here by direct approach creating an own dbcontext provider each microservice I use in my project.

Comment: Of course, I vould realize it by a reflection - noone can stop me to check 'ToListAsync' signature and ask QueryableExtensions to give me an appropriate ToListAsync method for direct calling through reflection. But I suppose that more elegant way to solve my task is available in ef core.

Comment: I see. Actually there isn't easy and/or elegant way. But the same is for regular synchronous queryable methods like `First`, `Count` etc, which are executed immediately rather than producing queryable expression. You can use `queryProvider.CreateQuery(expression)` to reconstruct the query as non generic `IQueryable`, but then again there is not much you can do with it because both sync and async "finalizator"s are generic methods. The best you could do would be to take `ElementType` from the reconstructed query and call desired generic methods via reflection.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, yeah, bad news for me - so, I think, I should use my current reflection based approach wrapping `finalizator` methods with an `ExpressionCall` and running it in the new `Task`...

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the query provider from your existing query like that:

```
  var provider = (IAsyncQueryProvider)dataQuery.Provider;
```

Afterwards create a new query with

```
  var newQuery = provider.CreateQuery<User>(expression);
```

and execute it as with any other query.